# mysql data insert in php

Tags: php, mysql, insert

let me explain my problem..actualy i have a table where patient report get stored and patient can have more than one test so the result for every report should be different on print, result is inserting differnt but the field **remark** and **nor** inserting same value for more than one test..
this is input field image of report
[image]

and the field row can increase acording to increase of tested by patient..
now i am using this for inserting in table

```
function save_report_content()
{
    $R=DIN_ALL($_REQUEST);
    $dt = time();
    foreach($R as $k=>$v)
    {
      $test_id = str_replace('rep_result_', '', $k);
        if(strstr($k, 'rep_result_'))
        {
            $content = $v;
            $SQL = "INSERT INTO report SET
                   rep_te_id   = '$test_id',
                   rep_result  = '$content',
                   record_id = '$R[payment_id]',
                   remark= '$R[remark]',
                   nor= '$R[nor]',
                   rep_date    = '$dt'";
```

now result is going differently in table but remark and nor same for more than one test
[image]
i spend so much time to recover this problem but did not succeed, if i miss any relevant info regarding this question then feel free to ask me, and thanks in advance, any idea will be appreciate highly....

Comment: Did you check printing $_REQUEST and what value you are getting from the form?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with  $test_id = str_replace('rep_result_', '', $k); and if(strstr($k, 'rep_result_'))  ?

Comment: One thing you should do is to use restrictions in the database so a combination of remark and nor must be unique (and maybe also rep_result). But I don't think this solves your actual question totally.

Comment: ya...i already have tried it... :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whats the structure of your form ?

```
<input name='nor[]' />
```

It should be an array to allow each rows value to come other wise just the last rows value will come ...

Answer (score 0):

when you are in the foreach .. you shouldn't use `$R[remark]` since you are using `$k=>$v`

it should be `$v['remark']`

Comment: ok what about the foreach variables .. you should use it like this. 


$v['nor']

Comment: OK I will try to help you .. I need the content of the array at any random input. Also, the code after the SQL statement